# Hacker hid folder/file with name pattern from Linux ls

Tags: find, security, ls

My server was hacked by internet hackers.

The server hides any files or folders with name pattern `*system-sleep*` from the `ls`/`find` command. I can use some commands like `chmod` to the hidden folder. But when I create any folder or file with same name/path pattern, it gets hidden.

I am curious about how could they do that? I have reviewed the `bashrc` files, they did not do anything like adding `--ignore` option to `ls`.

Comment: Seems like they modified something which is using getdents of linux. Anyone knows which binary or directory might have been hacked?

Comment: ... but remember, whatever you do, [contain the security problem](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231) first!

Comment: It might just be a "custom shell" or "custom ls" they put there instead (you could try checking the binaries - checksums etc). It's hard to tell just by that info. But be sure to be safe about expermienting with it as AdminBee said. If you want to reverse engineer it, I'd recommend making an offline copy of the harddrive (if you needed to, you could use it a vm for testing)

Comment: Thanks guys, I've tried by best to contain the problem for now. Seems like it's something in kernel module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They may have loaded a kernel module that hooks into the processing of the `getdents()` system call and removes matching directory entries from the results before they are returned to the userspace.

Using the `insmod` command, such a kernel module can be loaded from a non-default location, and it can also be deceptively named. It might also hide itself from the `lsmod` listing in much the same way: by hooking into the part of the kernel that produces the listing and removing its own name from it before passing the information onward.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know where I could identify the getdents() related kernel or kernel module file, so I could replace back with an original file? @telcoM

Comment: It is most likely somewhere in a directory named `system-sleep`. :-) But it is not a matter of replacing an existing file; it is an entirely new kernel module for the express purpose of hiding the intruder's tools.

Comment: @PleaseLetMeGo "Reparing" a compromised server is not what you want to do. You need to replace it and reinstall it from scratch (possibly with a restore from a known good backup). You may also want to consider doing the same to any directly connected systems as they may well be compromised as well.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231